# Adding barriers to a Network Analyst layer programmatically

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, network-analyst

Right now, I have code that allows the user to indicate on a map, which contains a Network Dataset layer, stops that are needed to create a route.  I need to add functionality to the interface that allows the user to also create barriers as well as stops.

The way this is normally done in ArcMap is as follows:

1. Create the route layer by clicking on **Network Analyst** and **New
   Route**
2. Make the Network Analyst window visible
3. Highlight the **Restriction** layer inside the **Line Barriers** layer
4. Click on the button for **Create Network Location Tool**
5. Draw the barrier on the map.

I already have implemented the ability to create stops by using `ControlsNetworkAnalystCreateLocationToolClass()`.

My question is, how can I also implement the capability of creating barriers as well as stops into my code?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered here . . .
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/44002-Working-on-C-code-that-will-allow-user-to-create-quot-Barriers-quot-on-a-map?p=151801&posted=1#post151801